# About a proof for $S_n$ being generated by adjacent transpositions

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know this is a standard result and I'm looking at the proof [here](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/algebra/notes/13.pdf) (Theorem 2.0.1)

I have one quick question about this proof.

The proof uses induction on $n$ by considering any permutation $p\in S_n$ and showing that there exists a product of adjacent transpositions $q$ s.t. $q\circ p(n)=n$. Then $q\circ p$ can be viewed as a permutation in $S_{n-1}$.

I understand what $q$ is and that $q\circ p\in S_{n-1}$ and thus $q\circ p$ can be expressed as a product of adjacent transpositions by induction hypothesis. But why does that mean $p$ can be expressed as a product of adjacent transpositions?

Comment: If $p(n)=i<n$ then $(i,i+1)\circ p(n)=i+1$, if $I+1=n$ done, otherwise apply $(1+1,2+i)\circ((I,i+1)\circ p(n)=I+2$ and sp on, at some point you get a product of transpositions $q:=\tau_j\circ\ldots\circ \tau_i$ such that $q\circ p(n)=n$. By assumption $r=q\circ p$ is product of transpositions and so $p-q^{-1}\circ r$ is the product of transpositions ($q^{-1}=\tau_1\circ\ldots \circ\tau_j$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $q$ is a composition of adjacent transpositions, and so is $q\circ p$. But $p=q^{-1}\circ(q\circ p)$, and so $P$ is also a composition of adjoint transpositions.

Comment: But in the proof, $q\circ p(n)=n$ and not necessarily $q\circ p(i)=i$ for $i<n$?

Comment: That answer was wrong and I've edited it.